# Nested AND and OR conditions on find methods (not queryBuilder)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

Precondition: I'm using Typeorm to perform database queries and I can't use the `queryBuilder` methods to create this query, but only the `find` method.

I need to translate a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM address where zip = 123 and (street = 'asd' or city = 'New York');
```

I know that the solution can be trivial using the usual `queryBuilder`, but in this particular case I cannot use it.

Is it possible to implement these nested and/or conditions only using the `find` method?

Comment: is this on an array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Soory @Anthony, but it involves the use of the Typeorm library, it is not on a array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try this?

```
Address.find([{
  zip: 123, street: 'asd'
}, {
  zip: 123, city: 'New York'
}]);
```

if you have just `and`, `or` conditions, yes! it's possible to implement the query only with `find` method.
In `typeorm` query, you can represent `or` with the array of the conditions.

```
zip = 123 and (street = 'asd' or city = 'New York')
```

is same as

```
(zip = 123 and street = 'asd') or (zip = 123 and city = 'New York')
```

Comment: Well, you are right. The problem is that inverting the position of the OR and AND conditions can generate a less efficient query. But, at the moment, it seems to be the unique possibility.